# How can I stop the word "Search" from showing up in the bootstraptable search?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

Please help.  We require dual language (English / French) so ideally, that word should be something like "Search / Recherche".  So barring that, I would like to just disable it and maybe create a label on top.  Is this possible?

Thanks much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: already searhed. nothing so far...  i don't want to implement my own custom search box.  only looking to see if i can change the word inside that box.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify localisations individually by calling

```js
$('#your-table-id').bootstrapTable({
  formatSearch: function () {
    return 'Search / Recherche'
  }
})
```

See the relevant [docs](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/localizations/#formatsearch) for more info.